# Passing keyboard events from NSTextView to another

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, appkit, nstextview

I have `NSTextView` which pops up a `NSPopOver` that contains another `NSTextView`. In some cases, I'd like to pass the keyboard events (arrow keys, mostly) from the "top" text view to the bottom one.

I have overridden `keyDown` on the topmost text view and tried various ways of forwarding the keyboard event to the view below.

Just calling `bottomTextView.keyDown(with: event)` doesn't do anything. The closest I've gotten is using `window.sendEvent(event)`.

```swift
override func keyDown(with event: NSEvent) {
    if (NSLocationInRange(Int(event.keyCode), NSMakeRange(123, 4)) &&
        self.string.count == 0 && event.modifierFlags.contains(.shift)) {
        // Pass the event through somehow
        return
    }
    
    super.keyDown(with: event)
}
```

Through trial and error, I found one way which actually did pass on the events: calling the methods *twice*.

```swift
// Make the bottom text field first responder
self.window?.makeFirstResponder(self.delegate.bottomTextView)
self.window?.makeFirstResponder(self.delegate.bottomTextView)
// Send the keydown event to window
self.window?.sendEvent(event)
self.window?.sendEvent(event)
```

However, this causes strange issues, such as the topmost text view getting a one-byte string as its contents.

Is there a correct way to actually forward any key events from a text view to another, or is it even possible?

Comment: Can the top text view access the bottom one? Can the top text view do `bottomTextView.keyDown(with: event)`?

Comment: This is what I've attempted, but didn't document that in my question for some reason. I'll edit that in, but no, that doesn't seem to work, not even in a blank project.

Comment: From where and how do you pop up the pop over?

Comment: From `NSTextView` subclass, using `selectionDidChange` notification. I'm actually not sure if `keyDown` events can be passed as-is anyways, because they seem to look into things like if the key is still pressed down etc., and seem to get invalidated.

Comment: Your question should be improved: how are you setting up the views: do you use IB or do you do that programmatically, and if so, how? That has a huge importance how the responder chain is set up. If the responder chain is not set up properly, this is what you get.

Comment: I'll try improving the question and perhaps create a sample project. It's a complicated responder chain, but the bottom `NSTextView` is referred to via a delegate, while the top one is loaded from a `xib`.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to use `addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching:handler:)`?